# Serving static content with GoLang Webserver

Tags: go

I'm exploring the depths of Go, and I've been trying to write a simple web application to wrap my head around everything. I'm trying to serve a React.js application.

Below is the code of the Go server. I've got the default route of `/` serving the `index.html` which is working fine. I'm struggling to allow static files to be served to that index file. I'm allowing the React App to do it's own client side routing, although I need to statically serve the JavaScript / CSS / Media files.

For example, I need to be able to serve the `bundle.js` file into the `index.html` for the React application to run. Currently, when I route to `localhost:8000/dist/` I see the files being listed, but every file/folder that I click from there is throwing a `404 Page Not Found`. Is there something that I'm missing? A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Webserver.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type ServerConfig struct {
    Environment string
    Host string
    HttpPort int
    HttpsPort int
    ServerRoot string
    StaticDirectories []string
}

func ConfigureServer () ServerConfig {
    _, err := os.Stat("env.toml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Config file is missing: env.toml")
    }

    var config ServerConfig
    if _, err := toml.DecodeFile("env.toml", &config); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return config
}

func IndexHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./src/index.html")
}

func main () {
    Config := ConfigureServer()
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    // Configuring static content to be served.
    router.Handle("/dist/", http.StripPrefix("/dist/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))))

    // Routing to the Client-Side Application.
    router.HandleFunc("/", IndexHandler).Methods("GET")

    log.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("Starting HTTP Server on Host %s:%d.", Config.Host, Config.HttpPort))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", Config.Host, Config.HttpPort), router); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully someone better versed in Gorilla can answer your question. Is there a reason you're using gorilla mux for this? It seems like the stdlib mux would handle this just fine.

Comment: I don't think that it's the library that's causing issues. I've tried this with removing the Gorilla and I'm getting the same issue. Reasoning for Gorilla was to see what it's all about for the API and Auth service at a later point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [gorilla mux docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux), the proper way to do this would be a handler registered with `PathPrefix`, like this:

```
router.PathPrefix("/dist/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/dist/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))))
```

An example can be found if you search the docs for something like `PathPrefix("/static/")`.

---

This wildcard behavior actually comes by default with the pattern matching mechanism in net/http, so if you weren't using gorilla, but just the default net/http, you could do the following:

```
http.Handle("/dist/", http.StripPrefix("/dist/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with file access path. Try:

```
// Strip away "/dist" instead of "/dist/"
router.Handle("/dist/", http.StripPrefix("/dist", http.FileServer(http.Dir("dist"))))
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The URL in the browser or cURL is `http://localhost:8000/dist/filename.js`. I'll do some logging to make sure of the request vs the filename maybe.

Comment: If the handle URL is the same as the StripPrefix then it removes the `/dist/` from the URL once you try access the file.