# Trying to serve React SPA that uses react-router

Tags: go

Im using Gorilla/Mux for routing and want to serve the React SPA regardless of the URL path.

```
func main() {
fmt.Println("server running...")

hub := newHub()
go hub.run()

router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/api/create", Api)
router.HandleFunc("/api/getpoll", Api)
router.HandleFunc("/api/update", Api)

router.HandleFunc("/sockets/{id}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r 
*http.Request) {
    Socketme(hub, w, r)
})

//  router.HandleFunc("/{rest:.*}", emberHandler)
router.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(serveFile)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router))
}

 func serveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/build")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Dont want Go to give 404s the Spa should be handling these routes.

Answer (score 1):

The [Router](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router) exports a `NotFoundHandler` field which you can set to your custom handler.

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.NotFoundHandler = MyCustom404Handler
```

So you could do something like:

```
router.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./public/build/index.html")
}))
```

so that it always serves your index page when it would normally return a `404`

Comment: router.NotFoundHandler only accepts a handler, cant get this to work.

Comment: ...so wrap it in `http.HandlerFunc`

Answer (score 0):

So I couldnt find any workable solutions to this. So I ended up taking a different approach using mux.Subrouter found here [Static file server in Golang using gorilla/mux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630547/static-file-server-in-golang-using-gorilla-mux)